# Appending a string to an array

Tags: java, arrays

I have to write a function that prepends if boolean is true or append if boolean is false a string to an array. I'm not exactly sure what this means? Do I just add a string to the first element of the array if I'm prepending or add a string to the last element of the array if I'm appending? Or what?

Comment: Question isn't that clear but since this is homework you should ask some doubts to your proff. or teacher and get it clarified.

Comment: It sounds to me like you are supposed to write a function which takes a boolean flag. However, the assignment itself is ambiguous. It hasn't clearly described what you're supposed to append/prepend the string _to_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That could either mean append the String to the last String of the array or add a new element in your array.

But I really think that's about adding elements in an array (either at the start or at the end of the array).

Answer (score 1):

Well the question states that append string to array depending on Boolean. Convert string to array and add each character to the Array. Appending to easy and for pre-pending you need to write a array routine to move the array elements to provide space for pre-pending string characters.

Answer (score 0):

You could user StringBuilder instead of using array 
and just append ur string at the first of the stringBulder .
E.g:
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
str.append("everyBody");
str.insert(0, "hello ");
System.out.println(str.toString());

Comment: As it's an assignment I don't think he can bend the rules ;)